# Are there any warp voting functions in OpenCL?

Tags: cuda, opencl

In CUDA there are `__ballot()`, `__any()`, `__all()`, `__popc()` and a bunch of lanemask functions to perform warp voting operations across all lanes (usually with the size of 32) within a warp. I'm wondering is there any such functions implemented in OpenCL to perform the same operations within one wavefront. If there is no such function, I may need to implement them as inline functions myself to use in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [OpenCL v. 1.1 specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf), section 6.11 "Built-in Functions", I believe that the answer is no.

However on NVIDIA GPUs, you can probably use inline PTX to implement these things (or at least [this blogger was able to use inline PTX](http://www.whatmannerofburgeristhis.com/blog/gcn-opencl-memory-fences-update-and-inline-ptx/)).

Comment: Actually after I brought up this question I realized it probably won't be any built-in functions like these due to OpenCL's cross platform capability. Any hardware specific function implementation would be unacceptable I guess. However your last comment gives me some hope. I'd be happy if someone has made inline functions using AMD's IL for AMD's hardware :-P

Comment: Yes, but, we can probably use ineline assembler on nvidia, and subgroups opencl on everything else

Answer (score 2):

Actually check out OpenCL [subgroups](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_subgroups.html).  They define some cross lane functions like `sub_group_all()` and `sub_group_any()` as well as something other interesting things.

Subgroups are a relatively new critter and I am not sure who all supports it. The Intel GPU implementation (extension actually) has a few more interesting [shuffling functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/intel/cl_intel_subgroups.txt) to permute lanes (within the register file) as well as to make explicit block writes and reads.  I bet AMD also supports subgroups, but I am not sure about NVidia.